# Mongoose 3.1.0: Why the callback in the connection.db.dropDatabase(callback) is never called and the DB is not DROPPED?

Tags: mongoose

Code:

```
var connection = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost:9000/' + databaseName);
connection.db.dropDatabase(function(err){
    // never reach this point!
    debugger;
    console.log(err);
    console.log('-------------->Dropped database: ' + databaseName);
});
```

If I do connection.open it says that it's already opening and no multiple calls to "open" are supported for the same connection.

Even this doesn't work

```
var conn = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost',databaseName, 9000, {}, function(){
    console.log('created'); // is reached
    conn.db.dropDatabase(callback); // but the callback is not called anyway
});
```

What is the problem? ("mongoose": "3.1.0")
The database is not even dropped...
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    var connection = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost:9000/' + databaseName, function(err){
        connection.db.dropDatabase(function(err){
                         // now it works!
                    })
    });
```

The problem is that the dropDatabase command was not queued and not run when the connection opened. So if I used a callback on the createConnection then it worked and drop the db after this, it worked!

Comment: Didn't you already try this in the `Even this doesn't work` part of your original post?

Comment: Well, there is a little diference: in the "question" I've been passed the db as argument instead of concatenating in the string like in the "answer". That was the trick from what I know.

Comment: The `{}` parameter in the original looks suspicious.  What was that there for?

Comment: I don't remember where I've saw but I think that were some arguments for the connection.. I can't find the answer right now